# Cannot expand steps or see logs in Blue Ocean after Jenkins upgrade to 2.303.2

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

we recently upgraded Jenkins to version 2.303.2. We also upgraded the below listed Blue Ocean plugins. As we do not have the main Blue Ocean plugin installed, we upgraded all the compatible Blue Ocean related plugins seperately. There are few Blue Ocean related plugins that are non-compatible and we couldn't upgrade them. After upgrade, we are not able to expand the steps in the Blue Ocean. Due to this we are not able to see the logs in the Blue Ocean. This is a consmetic issue but still it affects the users. Any idea what can be wrong here and how can this be rectified?

**Blue Ocean related plugins that are currently installed:**

```
Bitbucket Pipeline for Blue Ocean  --> 1.24.8
Blue Ocean Core JS  --> 1.25.2
Blue Ocean Pipeline Editor  --> 1.24.8
Common API for Blue Ocean  --> 1.25.2
Config API for Blue Ocean  --> 1.25.2
DEPRECATED Blue Ocean Executor Info  --> 1.25.2
Display URL for Blue Ocean  --> 2.4.1
Events API for Blue Ocean  --> 1.24.8
Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean  --> 1.24.8
GitHub Pipeline for Blue Ocean  --> 1.24.8
JIRA Integration for Blue Ocean  --> 1.25.2
Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean  --> 1.24.8
Pipeline SCM API for Blue Ocean  --> 1.25.2
REST API for Blue Ocean  --> 1.25.2
Web for Blue Ocean  --> 1.25.2
```

**Non-compatible Blue Ocean plugins those we couldn't upgrade:**

```
Bitbucket Pipeline for Blue Ocean (couldn't upgrade to 1.25.2)
Blue Ocean Pipeline Editor (couldn't upgrade to 1.25.2)
Events API for Blue Ocean (couldn't upgrade to 1.25.2)
Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean (couldn't upgrade to 1.25.2)
GitHub Pipeline for Blue Ocean (couldn't upgrade to 1.25.2)
Pipeline implementation for Blue Ocean (couldn't upgrade to 1.25.2)
```

We tried to install the main Blue Ocean plugin, but it gave a warning:
`Warning: This plugin requires newer versions of dependencies and at least one of those plugins is not compatible with the installed version. This is usually the case because its behavior changed, or it uses a different settings format than the installed version. Jobs using that plugin may need to be reconfigured, and/or you may not be able to cleanly revert to the prior version without manually restoring old settings. Consult the plugin release notes for details.`

We did not proceed as this will require re-configuration of our Jobs.